# In Angular 6, how do I load ngx-mydatepicker when I'm not using SystemJS?

Tags: angular, webpack, datepicker, systemjs

I am trying to implement the following datepicker: 
https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker/blob/master/README.md

The HTML, according to the docs:

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  style="float:none"
  placeholder="Select a date"
  ngx-mydatepicker // throws error
  name="mydate"
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  [options]="myOptions"
  #dp="ngx-mydatepicker" 
  (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"
/>
```

But I get the error `There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngx-mydatepicker"`.

According to the docs, it says if I'm using SystemJS I should do the following:
[image]

which I guess would solve the error I get, but I am not using SystemJS. I run Angular 6 built with the AngularCLI.

What is the proper way to import/load the `ngx-mydatepicker` package without SystemJS?

Comment: ... huh? SystemJS setup is point 3 in the readme. You are not using SystemJS so you should do point 2 (and also point 1, npm install it).

Comment: I have done everything you mention and what the guide says and am getting the error, since they don't provide a way to load "ngx-mydatepicker" without SystemJS.

Comment: Point 2 **is** the configuration needed. There is no hint however that the component is compatible with Angular 6 and there have been no commits for two months. You may simply be out of luck for now and will need to use a different datepicker. For example: [angular materials](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

Answer (score 1):

> you need to expose your directive public API to your template.

Just make the couple of changes -

### in ts

Put the exportAs in Directive declaration.

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[ngx-mydatepicker]',
 exportAs: 'ngxMydatepicker'    //<-- expose to outer world.
})
```

### in html

```
input
  class="form-control"
  style="float:none"
  placeholder="Select a date"
  ngx-mydatepicker // throws error
  name="mydate"
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  [options]="myOptions"
  #dp="ngxMydatepicker"  <!-- exposed directive -->
  (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

The solution is on the app.module.ts I have forgot to put this import

```
import { NgxMyDatePickerModule } from 'ngx-mydatepicker/dist/ngx-my-date-picker.module';
```

and this on the imports:

```
[
    NgxMyDatePickerModule.forRoot()
]
```